# Add value to non-existant array element

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with PHP 5.3 and need to add values to non-existant array elements.

Here is an example of what the array may look like:

```
$a[1] = 10;
$a[3] = 30;
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
$a[2] += 5;
```

I know about array_fill(). But the problem is I don't know what the maximum range is going to be.

Right now I have this:

```
if (!isset($a[2])) $a[2] = 0;
$a[2] += 5;
```

This does the trick, but, of course, if there is a 'built-in' way to do this in PHP, I'd prefer that method.

Comment: Your current solution is just fine, there is no real reason to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built in php function to handle this. You'll have to use something like what you've already got. Your current solution is also very easy to read and does exactly what it's meant to.

Answer (score -1):

You could use array_replace() to set a default value before accessing the specific index:

```
$a = array();
$a = array_replace(array(2 => 0), $a);
$a[2] += 5;
var_dump($a);

array(1) {
 [2]=>
 int(5)
}
```

Comment: What if `$a[2]` was already initialized with 42? PS: -1 not mine, but I do agree that it would break the existing data

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly, but if `$a` already has a value for the index 2, it is preserved.